# LOAD CSV is not working when reading in AS line in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I don't understand where this `AS` statement is going wrong.

This works fine:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH SPLIT(line.`date`, '/') AS date
RETURN date
```

and I get the date returned. This must mean there was no problem with the `AS date` part.

However, when I continue and try to break a date up, I get an error saying
`line not defined (line 4, column 27 (offset: 156))`

Here's the code that fails:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH SPLIT(line.`date`, '/') AS date
CREATE (n:Node  {id: line.`id_from_csv`})
SET n.year= TOINT(date[2])
```

What about the `WITH SPLIT` ruined my `AS line`?

Answer (score 1):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///some_csv.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.`date`, '/') AS date
CREATE (n:Node  {id: line.`id_from_csv`})
SET n.year= TOINT(date[2])
```

should work (untested). The moment you introduce the WITH, it's like a boundary between the previous part of the query and the current path, so at post point, `line` is out of scope unless you choose to carry it forward.